# No me funciona el "<p-columnFilter [showMatchModes]="false"> de PrimeNG

Tags: html, angular, primeng, ts

soy algo nuevo en angular, estoy usando una p-table (de PrimeNG) y necesito borrar el icono de filtro, el código es el siguiente:
 `<p-columnFilter showMatchModes="false" matchMode='contains' type="text" field="name"></p-columnFilter>`
pero me sigue mostrando el icono he intentado usar otras propiedades, siempre con el mismo resultado.
¿Qué estoy haciendo mal? he buscado información y no encuentro,
gracias
pd: el matchMode si me esta funcionando correctamente.

Comment: Hola bienvenido a Stackoverflow, por favor has el [tour] para entender cómo funcionamos y de paso ganar tu primer medalla. Te recomiendo que leas [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Debes colocar el código de lo que hayas intentado hasta el momento. Te sugiero que leas [example] para que sea más fácil entender lo que buscas. Recuerda que debes demostrar que has investigado previamente antes de recurrir a preguntar. Saludos

Comment: Hola Rolex puedes probar, [showMenu]="false", ya que así lo controla angular y en este caso lo coge valor y no variable, solo en el caso de valores boolanos.

Comment: Muchas gracias por sus respuestas, había entendido mal el concepto y no todo se aplica a lo que quería hacer, pensé que eso desactivaría el menú desplegable he optado por crear inputs de búsqueda propios, ya que personalizar el ya mencionado me estaba constando mucho. agradezco nuevamente y me pasare por las secciones mencionadas para a futuro realizar una mejor pregunta.